# Return one word at a time

Tags: python, function, text-files

I have a function that takes in a text file and prints each word in the file one by one, each on a new line.

---

Here's the code that does what I said above:

```
def print_one_word():
    with open("test_script.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        word_current = []
        for line in lines:
            for word in line.split():
                word_current.append(word)
                print("".join(word_current))
                word_current.clear()
```

**Example, with specified text file content:**

`test_script.txt` has the content (as formatted): `stack, hello test python's name`

The function `print_one_word()` will print the following to stdout (as formatted):

```
stack,  
hello  
test  
python's  
name
```

---

The goal is to pass each word, one by one, into a second function that will perform some operations on it (Ex: capitalize the first letter). However, *the most important part* is that it sends to the second function only one word, and once the operation is performed, the next word is sent.

To do this, I've replaced `print` with `return`, after realizing that that wouldn't work (would only send one word), I tried using `yield`. However, it still only sends one word to the second function and then stops (it won't continue sending the following words).

I've also tried methods besides what I have currently (creating a list of one word, printing that list without formatting, and then clearing the list), such as simply printing `word` and so forth. Unfortunately, I got the same result; I could print each word one at a time, but not send to the second function each word one at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Edit, for clarity:**
The second function takes in an argument, and I use the first function as the argument.
**Example:**

```
def operation(script):
    does some things
```

`operation(print_one_word())`

Comment: you can use `yield` by loading into a list `words = list(print_one_word())` and pass that list to the second function or `for word in words: function...`

Comment: still don't understand why do you append one word to a list then clear this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store all the words into a list and then call whatever function you want (in this case I'm calling `do_something()` on them afterwards:

```
def do_something(word):
  print(word.upper())

def print_one_word():
    with open("test_script.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        all_words = []
        for line in lines:
            for word in line.split():
                all_words.append(word)
                print(word)

    for word in all_words:
      do_something(word)

print_one_word()
```

output:

```
stack,
hello
test
python's
name
STACK,
HELLO
TEST
PYTHON'S
NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to return a list and yield from functions, keep in mind `yield` returns a generator object and if you want to reuse yielded results you need to listify them:

```py
def yield_words():
    with open("test_script.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word

def list_words():
    with open("test_script.txt", "r") as f:
        return [word
                for line in f.readlines()
                for word in line.split()]

def operation(prefix, word):
    print(f'{prefix} {word}')

yielded_words = list(yield_words())
listed_words = list_words()

for word in listed_words:
    operation('listed', word)

for word in yielded_words:
    operation('yielded', word)
```

Output:

```
listed this
listed is
listed a
listed test
listed hello
listed there
yielded this
yielded is
yielded a
yielded test
yielded hello
yielded there
```